# Как поместить диалоговое окно в Java апплет?

Tags: java, исключения, applet

Приветствую всех. Столкнулся с такой задачей: нужно вывести в апплете на html странице диалоговое окно для выбора файлов для последующей его передаче в javascript. Будучи полным профаном в Java нашел такой код:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class GetFilePuth extends Applet {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
                JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
                new MyFrame();
            }
        });
    }
}

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    public MyFrame() {
        super("Тестовое окно");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        panel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());

        final JLabel label = new JLabel("Выбранный файл");
        label.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        panel.add(label);

        panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10, 10)));

        JButton button = new JButton("Показать JFileChooser");
        button.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFileChooser fileopen = new JFileChooser();
                int ret = fileopen.showDialog(null, "Открыть файл");
                if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File file = fileopen.getSelectedFile();
                    String fullname = file.getPath();
                                        label.setText(fullname);
                }
            }
        });

        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
        getContentPane().add(panel);

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(260, 220));
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Однако при открытии страницы апплет выдает ошибку, хотя .jar файл открывается и отрабатывается нормально без ошибок. В чем тут проблема? Буду весьма признателен за советы и помощь. Заранее благодарю.

Код ошибки:

> load: class getfileputht not found.
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> getfileputht  at
> sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown
> Source)   at
> sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown
> Source)   at
> sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown
> Source)   at
> sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown
> Source)   at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown
> Source)   at
> sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown
> Source)   at
> sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown
> Source)   at
> sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown
> Source)   at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> Exception:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> getfileputht load: class
> GetFilePuth.jar not found.
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> GetFilePuth.jar   at
> sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown
> Source)   at
> sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown
> Source)   at
> sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown
> Source)   at
> sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown
> Source)   at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown
> Source)   at
> sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown
> Source)   at
> sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown
> Source)   at
> sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown
> Source)   at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> Exception:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> GetFilePuth.jar

Comment: попробуй положить GetFilePuth.class в папку со страничкой

Answer (score 1):

```
 <APPLET CODE="GetFilePuth.class" WIDTH="200" HEIGHT=100>
   </APPLET>
```

это надо поместить на страничку, что бы вставился аплет

Comment: На странице код такой:
<P>
<APPLET codebase="getfileputh" code="GetFilePuth.jar" width=350 height=200></APPLET>
</P>

Comment: Ну попробуй поставить мой, лучше бы не код программы кинул, а текст ошибки

Comment: Добавил код ошибки в текст топика

Comment: <code>path</code> или <code>puth</code>, как же правильно...

Comment: А для названия класса это принципиально?